# How to make triangles connected with corners of rectangle in svg?

Tags: html, svg

I am new to svgs. How can i make 4 triangles attached with border inside a rectangle? See the Attached image.

[image]

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Use a SVG editor such as Inkscape and draw whatever shape you want.

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like :

```
<polygon points="34.2,87.4 12.3,65.5 12.3,34.5 34.2,12.6 65.2,12.6 87.1,34.5 87.1,65.5 65.2,87.4" fill="hsl(216,80%,50%)"/>
```

https://codepen.io/anon/pen/pWyxLX //octogone only

https://codepen.io/anon/pen/ZXWVKo //using 4 triangles

Comment: How I will show the stroke on sides? This is only showing the ploygon

Comment: @Nosheen i forgot read the topic here using 4 trirangles, regards. https://codepen.io/anon/pen/ZXWVKo

Answer (score 0):

Here is a sample SVG that looks like your requested shape.

Explaining every element is beyond the scope of a Stack Overflow answer, but there are plenty of books and web tutorials to explain the various features of SVGs. Plus you can always [read the SVG specification](https://www.w3.org/TR/SVG/single-page.html).

```html
<svg width="200" height="200" viewBox="0 0 100 100">

  <!-- The rect around the outside -->
  <!-- 80 width and high, centred in the middle -->
  <rect x="10" y="10" width="80" height="80"
        fill="none" stroke="black" stroke-width="2" />
  
  <!-- Now add triangles in the corners -->
  <!-- You could use paths or polygons ->
  <!-- I'll use both for comparison purposes -->
  <polygon points="10,10, 40,10, 10,30"
           fill="black"/>
  <polygon points="90,10, 60,10, 90,30"
           fill="black"/>
  <!-- The final two corners we will use a <path> -->
  <!-- And use a variety of path commands for fun -->
  <path d="M 10,90 L 40,90 L 10,70 Z"
           fill="black"/>
  <path d="M 60,90 H 90 V 70 Z"
           fill="black"/>

</svg>
```